# Burnside/Cauchy-Frobenius Theorem Application

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose a finite group $G$ acts transitively on a finite set $X$ awith $|X| > 1$. Prove that there is some element $g \in G$ that fixes no element of $X$.
>
> Hint: Think about the Burnside/Cauchy-Frobenius Theorem (Proposition 5.2.2).

> **Proposition 5.2.2** *(Burnside's lemma). Let a finite group $G$ act on a finite set $X$. Then the number of orbits of the action is*
>
> $$ \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |\text{Fix}(g)|.$$

Reviewing for a test and I came across this. I'm having a little trouble interpreting this. G is finite so 1/|G| is some fraction. Then there is the Summation of the cardinality of Fix(g) but I'm confused how the two come together to prove that there is a g that fixes no element of X.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users of the site have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Answer (score 3):

(1) suppose every $g\in G$ fixes some $x\in X$. In other words,  $Fix(g)$ is non-empty for every $g\in G$.

(2) We do something more: when $g$ is identity, then what is $Fix(g)$?

(3) Since $G$ acts transitively, 
(the number of orbits)=(above expression in question)=1.

(4) Can you proceed to arrive at contradiction? [Hint: Split above sum as 
$$\frac{1}{|G|} |Fix(identity)| +\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G-\{1\}}|Fix(g)|. \,\,\,\,] $$

Answer (score 3):

From the Proposition 5.2.2, the action is transitive if and only if:
$$\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname {Fix}(g)\right|=|G|\tag 1$$
Let's set $G=\{e,g_1,\dots,g_{n-1}\}$; since $\operatorname {Fix}(e)=X$, if *every* $g_i$ fixes some $x\in X$, then there are *positive* integers $l_i$ ($i=1,\dots,n-1$) such that the LHS of $(1)$ is:
$$|X|+l_1+\dots+l_{n-1}\tag 2$$
But since all the $l_i$'s are positive, $(2)\ge |X|+|G|-1>|G|$ as soon as $|X|>1$, thus contradicting $(1)$. Therefore, *some* $g_i$ must fix no element of $X$.